# Connect by DSN fails with "invalid username or password", but DSN does have correct username and password

Tags: python, pyodbc, vertica

I'm attempting to connect to a vertica database from OS/X 10.10.2 using the following small script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys

import pyodbc

def usage(retval):
    if retval == 0:
        file_ = sys.stdout
    else:
        file_ = sys.stderr

    file_.write('Usage: {} --query sql_query --dsn data_source_name\n'.format(sys.argv[0]))

    sys.exit(retval)

def main():
    query = None
    dsn = None
    while sys.argv[1:]:
        if sys.argv[1] == '--query':
            query = sys.argv[2]
            del sys.argv[1]
        elif sys.argv[1] == '--dsn':
            dsn = sys.argv[2]
            del sys.argv[1]
        elif sys.argv[1] in {'-h', '--help'}:
            usage(0)
        else:
            sys.stderr.write('{}: Unrecognized option: {}\n'.format(sys.argv[0], sys.argv[1]))
            usage(1)
        del sys.argv[1]

    if query is None:
        sys.stderr.write('{}: --query is a required option\n'.format(sys.argv[0]))
        usage(1)

    if dsn is None:
        sys.stderr.write('{}: --dsn is a required option\n'.format(sys.argv[0]))
        usage(1)

    connection_string = 'DSN={}'.format(dsn)
    sys.stderr.write('connection_string is {}\n'.format(connection_string))
    connection = pyodbc.connect(connection_string)
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute(query)

    # Fetchall might be faster, but it also has memory limit issues
    for row in cursor:
        print(row)


main()
```

Invoking this script like so:

```
ODBCINI=/Library/ODBC/odbc.ini /simple-connect --query 'select * from GLITCH.METRIC' --dsn GLITCH_ADMIN
```

...fails with:

```
21L, 1L, u"FAILED: ('28000', '[28000] FATAL 3781:  Invalid username or password\\n (3781) (SQLDriverConnect)')", u'unique_seconds', ...
```

...plus a little more text on the same line, and one additional line which I've deleted for protection.

I have another (much larger) program that connects fine using the same DSN, without prompting for a username or password.

The relevant DSN in /Library/ODBC/odbc.ini looks like (hostname, username and password changed for protection) :

```
Driver      = Vertica
Description = Glitch Vertica Meta Data DSN
Database    = Analytics
Servername  = hostname
UID         = username
PWD         = password
PORT        = 5433
SSLMode     = require
```

I dtruss'd the script, and found that it was looking in /Library/ODBC/odbc.ini - or rather, it does with the ODBCINI environment variable set appropriately.  Without that variable, it appeared to be ignoring my odbc.ini.

Does anyone know why it's failing to authenticate?

Thanks!

Comment: I have since tried two additional known-good DSN's, and they show the same problem.

Comment: I also tried setting ODBCINSTINI and ODBCSYSINI, but they didn't appear to help even as much as setting ODBCINI did.

Comment: This is with CPython 2.7.6 (an old version of the reference implementation of Python).

Comment: A DBA said he was seeing the query come in, but then the results were rolled back and nothing was done with the results.  So I tried turning on autocommit, but still no result.

Comment: The script now works unmodified with 3 good DSN's, but fails with 3 other good DSN's!  The 3 successful ones are a different server from the 3 unsuccessful ones. This is rather baffling.

Comment: BTW, the error message has a strange reference to one of two usernames that shouldn't be involved - it's not always the same username, even though I'm not changing the username with which the script tries to connect.  I'm not at all confident that it's trying to log in as one of those usernames - the DBA saw things coming in with the right username.

Comment: To demonstrate that the database was behaving, the DBA logged into the trouble-related server with the same creds, and showed that my query ran OK using Aquadata.

Comment: Does anyone have any suggestions, or is everyone just assuming my caps lock key is on?